# How to combine duplicates in an html table?

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, express

I'm a junior developer working on my first project. I'm trying to create a stats page in my application and am having a hard time figuring out how to display my data so it is easily readable. In similar applications I saw a table format used.

I've attached an image of my current app's stat page but it's producing a row for each individual database record. I'd like it to be able to combine duplicates under a given key (LP Name in this case), so I could easily see that Google has 3 clicks, Yahoo has 1 click, etc...

[Stats page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQzac.png)

I'm building my app in node & express (ejs for my template engine), using mongodb for my database. Can I only achieve this on the front end with Javascript & Jquery? (I'm unfamiliar with Jquery mostly) Can I achieve this through my back end stack somehow?

Right now, I'm simply looping through my database & displaying stored data:

```
<table class="ui striped table">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>LP Name</th>
        <th>URL</th>
        <th>Clicks</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
        <th>Conversions</th>
        <th>Revenue</th>
        <th>ROI</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% stats.forEach(function(stat){ %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= stat.visited.name %></td>
        <td><%= stat.visited.URL %></td>
        <td><%= stat.hit %></td></td>
        <td><%= stat.cost %></td></td>
        <td><%= stat.conversion.value %></td>
        <td><%= stat.conversion.amount %></td>
        <td>69%</td>
      </tr>
      <% }) %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Also, here is my route in express:

```
app.get("/campaigns/:id",function(req,res){
    Stat.find({cid:req.params.id},function(err,foundStats){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/");
        }else{
            res.render("campaigns/show",{stats:foundStats});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please show some code some input data

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a **[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have **[tried so far](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding **[how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**, and take the **[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do that is from backend, group the records while fetching them from mongodb based on LP Name this can be done easily using [mongodb aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)

update your route handler with the code below:

keep in mind that you need to update it with the correct database fields name ex: lp_name ...etc

```
app.get("/campaigns/:id", function(req, res) {
    Stat.aggregate([{
            $match: { cid: req.params.id }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: { _id: "$lp_name", _url: "$url" },
                price: { $sum: "$price" },
                clicks: { $sum: "$clicks" },
                cost: { $sum: "$cost" },
                conversions: { $sum: "$conversions" },
                revenue: { $sum: "$revenue" }
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                _id: 0,
                url: "$_id._url",
                lp_name: "$_id._id",
                price: 1,
                clicks: 1,
                cost: 1,
                conversions: 1,
                revenue: 1
            }
        }
    ], (err, foundStats) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/");
        } else {
            res.render("campaigns/show", { stats: foundStats });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I had errors first but this worked perfectly when I looked up the correct names in my Stat Schema. Thank you!

Comment: you are welcome, glad it helped ... please if this answered your question mark it as accepted ...